# Dynamic variables in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have four queries setup for each `sale_Dt` criteria and would like to consolidate into 1 query.

```
DEFINE SALE_DT = 20DEC2016;

Select 
STORE_ID,
SALES_FINAL_DT, 
SUM(SALES) AS TOTAL_sALE
From SALES_DB
Where SALES_FINAL_DT  = '&SALE_DT'
GROUP BY STORE_ID, SALES_FINAL_DT
```

I would like to make `SALE_DT` a dynamic variable that loops through `sale_Dt` for values `sale_dt = 20dec2016` and `sale_dt - 7`, `sale_dt - 8` and `sale_dt - 30`.

I will specify the sale date in the query.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OR` or an `IN` clause to specify the four variations on the date, e.g:

```
DEFINE SALE_DT = 20DEC2016;

select STORE_ID, SALES_FINAL_DT, SUM(SALES) AS TOTAL_SALE
from SALES_DB
where SALES_FINAL_DT = TO_DATE('&SALE_DT', 'DDMONYYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
or SALES_FINAL_DT = TO_DATE('&SALE_DT', 'DDMONYYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') - 7
or SALES_FINAL_DT = TO_DATE('&SALE_DT', 'DDMONYYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') - 8
or SALES_FINAL_DT = TO_DATE('&SALE_DT', 'DDMONYYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') - 30
group by STORE_ID, SALES_FINAL_DT;
```

You can also make the entire `to_date()` expression the substitution variable to simplify it slightly:

```
DEFINE SALE_DT = TO_DATE('20DEC2016', 'DDMONYYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')

select STORE_ID, SALES_FINAL_DT, SUM(SALES) AS TOTAL_SALE
from SALES_DB
where SALES_FINAL_DT = &SALE_DT
or SALES_FINAL_DT = &SALE_DT - 7
or SALES_FINAL_DT = &SALE_DT - 8
or SALES_FINAL_DT = &SALE_DT - 30
group by STORE_ID, SALES_FINAL_DT;
```

Or us `IN` to make it even shorter:

```
select STORE_ID, SALES_FINAL_DT, SUM(SALES) AS TOTAL_SALE
from SALES_DB
where SALES_FINAL_DT in (&SALE_DT, &SALE_DT - 7, &SALE_DT - 8, &SALE_DT - 30)
group by STORE_ID, SALES_FINAL_DT;
```

I've included the NLS data language parameter in the `to_date()` calls because you're using a string which assumes the session will understand `'DEC'`. If you use a numeric format you don't need to do that, e.g.

```
DEFINE SALE_DT = TO_DATE('2016-12-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

or as an ANSI date literal:

```
DEFINE SALE_DT = DATE '2016-12-20'
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, this is super helpful. Just out of curiosity, how would one deal with this if there were several (&SALE_DT - number) other than listing them in a where clause / using OR operator? How would I use a loop to do that? ...

Comment: @Aussie_Stats -  Using a loop doesn't really make sense. You'd have to use PL/SQL and then combine the result sets somehow (via a collection). It would be awkward and inefficient. You could, I suppose, use an inline view or CTE to generate the various offsets and then join that to your real table, but I'm not sure it would gain you much.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.